# flip thumbnail via button click

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found this sample and it looks good, so I put a thumbnail from bootstrap.

http://www.bootply.com/129165

And I like to implement it to the site my developing.

http://hotmeltcoatingmachines.com/

what I want is to flip the thumbnail thru button click.
How can I do that.

Thanks

```
 <div class="flip">
    <div class="card"> 
      <div class="face front"> 
        <div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>front</h3>
    <p>...</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Flip</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
      </div> 
      <div class="face back"> 
        <div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>back</h3>
    <p>...</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">flip</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

**sample code**
http://www.bootply.com/pZXSuyPPWx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @menaka will flip all the icons. If you want to flip only the icon that was clicked then use something like below:

```
$('.fliper-btn').click(function(e){

    $(e.target).closest('.flip').find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');

});
```

Make sure you keep the custom class `fliper-btn` as suggested by @menaka.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary fliper-btn" role="button">Flip</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

change JQuery code like this

```
$('.fliper-btn').click(function(){
    $('.flip').find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');

});
```

and give flip action buttons a custom class name like 'fliper-btn' and add it like this

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary fliper-btn" role="button">Flip</a>
```

Comment: Hi sir, there is a problem when there are 2 or more thumbnails, all of them flips if you click one of the buttons

Comment: then you have to specify the id of the button (in this case button class name) and id of the div (in this case also the div class name)....so you have 2 solutions=> 1) write separate events for every flip items in the page ,this will only work if there is only limited number of flip items =>next one is make the function dynamic and get a value from the click event still you have to specify the divs in a separate names